# Oracle trigger to restrict null value based on value from another table

Tags: oracle, triggers

Would you please give me a pseudo example of trigger code, how to deny (exception message) null value
in column1 in table1 based on value in column2 from table2.
Oracle 11g

Comment: Why not define that column as `NOT NULL` and create a foreign key?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Question caption: "Oracle trigger to restrict null value based on value from another table". This means that sometimes it can be null if I have understood it correctly.

Comment: @VBokšić: then a nullable column with a foreign key would do - the key point is that this sounds very much like an attempt to simulate foreign keys with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You need the trigger something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_NAME BEFORE
    INSERT OR UPDATE ON TABLE1
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( COLUMN1 IS NULL )
DECLARE
    V_CNT   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN 
      SELECT
          COUNT(1)
      INTO V_CNT
      FROM
          TABLE2
WHERE COLUMN2....; -- YOUR CONDITION, IF TRUE THEN NULL IN COLUMN1 WILL NOT BE ALLOWED

    IF V_CNT > 0 THEN
        RAISE; -- RAISE ERROR IF V_CNT IS NOT ZERO
    END IF;

END TRG_NAME;
/
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_n00b
  AFTER INSERT
  ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_column2 (something1 in number)  --here you get the value of column2 from table2
  IS
  SELECT column2
  FROM table2
  where something = :something1;
  v_column2 number;
BEGIN
  open  c_column2(table1.something1); -- here you can send some parameter to get the column2 value
  fetch c_column2 into v_column2;
  close c_column2;

  if v_column2 < 5 and :new.column1 is null THEN 
 /*this checks the value of column2 and the value of colum1 and if both of this are 
 true then you will rise the error*/
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 
    'Column1 of table11 can not be null if column2 is smaller than 5' );
  END IF;
END;
```